# PHP Laravel Blade @include pass data into WordPress query

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-blade

I'm using Sage 9 WordPress starter theme.https://github.com/roots/sage

After include the template in Laravel Blade and pass some data.

```
@include ('partials.filter-archive', ['taxonomy' => 'project-type'])
```

How could I use it in my template `partials.filter-archive` ??
`{{ $taxonomy }}` doesn't seem to work :(

```
@php
  $terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => {{ $taxonomy }},
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  ));
  print_r($terms);
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

I can actually simply just do this in `partials.filter-archive`, that worked for me.

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  ));

print_r($terms);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this once

```
@include ('partials.filter-archive', ['taxonomy' => "project-type"]);
```

and try to do this {{ $taxonomy }} before calling wp function, and check if its getting printed

Comment: It turns out when I do php echo $taxonomy, it prints, then I realised I can simply use it as a normal variable... thanks for the idea!